# How to show ACF repeater content in Woocommerce product tabs(description and additional info)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce, acfpro

I have 2 repeaters - image +text - that I have to show in the bottom of that 2 tabs.
I tried the way from woocommerce documentation

```
function woo_custom_description_tab_content() {?>
<div class="under-desc-wrapper">
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('adv') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('adv') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
       the_sub_field('adv_text');

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
</div>
<?php }
```

Fro the test I used only text, image had to be if I succeed. And pasted the same loop to the template of the tab, but the div is empty - no content from that repeaters.
It has to be like that by default and it has a special decision or somewhere i made a mistake?

Comment: Copy tabs templates in your theme woocommerce folder and add it. That is the best way to do it. You have this hook for additional info - woocommerce_product_additional_information if you want it this way and for description you have to use filter since its the_content function.

Comment: Or explain how you load woo_custom_description_tab_content since this is custom function. Also doing it this way you have to define product too if( have_rows('repeater', product_id ) ): - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

Comment: Now I try that in the tab template, but it doesn't help too

Comment: <div class="under-desc-wrapper">
<?php

global $post, $product, $woocommerce;
 
$product = wc_get_product();
 $product_id = $product->get_id();

if( have_rows('advs',  $product_id ) ):

  // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('advs',  $product_id ) ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value(yes, I renamed adv_text to adv-text - not a mistake)
         
  the_sub_field('adv-text',  $product_id);

    endwhile;

else :

   echo 'tadam';

endif;

?>
</div>